# Do I need to install Glassfish in the Java directory?

Tags: linux, jakarta-ee, glassfish, installation

I'm trying to install [JavaEE SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) on Linux.

In the installation process, it asks me about Glassfish installation directory.

**MyQuestion :**

Do I have to install Glassfish in the Java directory?

P.S :

I am using [Open JDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) which located in :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

No, you do not need to install Glassfish in the Java directory. Wherever you install it, as long as the access permissions, configurations are correct and java is in your path statement, it should run.